# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot boot without nomodeset on AMD APU

Tags: amd-graphics, 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04 cannot boot without nomodeset on AMD APU A8.
When I set nomodeset i only get 1024*768 resolution.

I've tried to install additional drivers but it seem fglrx is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

fglrx is no longer supported;

mesa is included with 18.04.

to see the current status:

glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: X.Org

OpenGL renderer string: AMD KAVERI (DRM 2.50.0, 4.15.0-20-generic, LLVM 6.0.0)

OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.0-devel